# Using Qt threads and passing large objects between threads. Am I just doing it wrong?

Tags: qt

I'm used to using boost_threads and hooking things together using thread safe queues and function calls that I roll myself.  However,  the signal and slots idiom of Qt seems really helpful for some things but not others.  For example,  for named pipes, it seems great for doing asynchronous communication that way.

That is until I have to pass the object I received over the named pipe to be translated and then send it off to another thread to translate the data and send it out.

The biggest issue I have is sending these messages back and forth through the 
signals and slots mechanism or perhaps using QMetaObject::invokeMethod().  It seems like this would get sent out using a Queued connection and if I understand correctly it copies the object being passed instead of passing it by reference or pointer.

This seems like it can get really inefficient if a lot of this is going to happen.  In my case it will be.  Is there a different way I should be approaching this issue?

Is there a way to just *insert an object into a queue by reference or pointer in a different thread*?

Comment: not an expert on the matter but, giving some code (in SSCCE manner, see: http://sscce.org/) would dramatically increase your chances of getting useful answers.

Comment: If you want to avoid your data being deep-copied, you can pass a pointer to your data through the signal/slot connection. However, I don't really understand how you're planning on using signals and slots across process boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like pointers can be passed to escape the copying that goes with passing by value.  I also found out that using boost::shared_ptr is recommended so that it will delete itself.  I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing between processes then you have to copy the data (ie marshal it across the process boundaries) or put it some where common that both processes can access. You can usually do the latter with shared memory, being careful about ownership.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  My original question wasn't clear enough.  My issue isn't passing between processes, but threads.  From what I read passing between threads in Qt does a copy instead of passing by reference or pointer.  This seems inefficient and the wrong way to go.